# rails count double entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, count, size, row

I have a join table:

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li><%= user.user_id %><%= user.user.name %></li>
```

gives me

- 1 fred
- 1 fred
- 9 charlie

Well.. thanks so far for the answers. I can see that I was not precise enough to explain what I need.

```
<% @users.each do |user| %>
<li><%= user.user_id %><%= user.user.name %></li>
```

is the result on an query. So the result could be 10 different user or some could be double or triple. I want to mark them when they appear multipe. I dont want to find out double entries in my database.....

So I have to find out weather in |user| are mutiple val with the same user_id..to get a true/false
Hope this makes it more clear.
Right now I dont have clou how to archieve this.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have two tables `users` and `details`

From a very little i got your question, i think you want all the users who has duplicate details

your sql should be like following

```
double_details = SELECT u.* FROM users u LEFT JOIN details on d.user_id = u.id 
                            GROUP BY 'u.user_id' HAVING (COUNT(d.id))  > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Model.group(:user_id).select("user_id, COUNT(*) as total").find_all{|i| i.total > 1}
```

Replace Model with your model.

Answer (score 0):

If the user table references itself, then something like `user.users.count` should return the amount of other users referencing this one.